# PHP Return in nested functions

Tags: php, function

I have a question about my functions. Let me explain, I have two functions:

```
/* This function works properly
; example : echo first('Hello world', 'return');
*/
function first($string, $return = 'echo')
{
 if($return == 'echo')
 {
  echo $string;
 }
 else
 {
  return $string;
 }
}
```

And this is second, function, is calling first function.

```
/* This function doesn't works
; example : echo second('my string', 'return');
*/
function second($string, $return = 'echo')
{
 first($string, $return);
}
```

The problem is I want the second function like that, as simple as above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to `return` from `second()`.  Otherwise, `first()`, called inside it, will `echo` output, but the value it returns to its caller (`second()`) goes nowhere and is lost.  Return the value of the call to `first()` from `second()`.

```
function second($string, $return = 'echo')
{
  return  first($string, $return);
}
```

Comment: Wow, looks legit :) thanks... That worksssss, sorry You can accept an answer in 8 minutes.

Comment: Exactly, you get the value from `first()` but `second()` didn't know what to do with it. So, it just stopped doing anything.